# Unexpected token error witout reasson

Tags: javascript

I try to implement bootstrap datepicker on one page and I write:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.someurl.com/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

but I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What is the reasn for this?

On every other page work well...

Comment: There's a mistake somewhere else on your page most likely. Post some more source.

Comment: but when I put this code etc. in this stackover flow page I get the same error...

Comment: Did you open the developer tools and paste that in? Are you using that tag within another script tag or a JavaScript file?

Comment: I dont understad question... i get just Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: When I try to call this: $("#nD").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "YYYY-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
   setDate: '2014-04-05',
    }); I get undefined is not a function ...

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you try to include a JavaScript file that has an unexpected `<` (as you might have guessed).

The most common cause of this is if you try to include a JavaScript file that doesn't exist, so you instead get a HTML page with a 404 error. Those pages usually start with `<html> [...]`, and thus JavaScript gets an unexpected `<`.

Comment: file excist and I include it into page but after when I try to run some function  I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: when I try to add this : $("#nD").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "YYYY-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
   setDate: '2014-04-05',
    }); I get undefinded is not a function